# How to kill processes from bash from newest to oldest

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, kill

Hello i am searching for a method to kill a browser's tabs (no preassinged processes) from bash terminal, by name not pid, and i want to delete them by order from newest to oldest. I tried

> pkill -f -n -9

and the browser's name but it doesn't kill all of them . I can't use killall because i want a short time of sleep between every killing of each process. Any suggestions?

Comment: How can you tell which pid is oldest

Comment: the -n switch automagically chooses the newest :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
while [[ $(pgrep -c "chromium") != 0 ]]
do
    pkill -n -9 "chromium"
    sleep 1
done
```

This will loop as long as there is a chromium process running. It waits 1 second between each kill. Also bash commands are space-sensitive ;-) . Keep spaces around brackets and comparison operators at all times.

Comment: after this 

>while [[ $( pgrep -c "$chromium" ) !=0 ]];
do
  pkill -n -9 "$chromium"
  sleep 1
done

It says 3 errors conditional binary operator expected , syntax error near !=0' , while [[ $( pgrep -c "$chromium" ) !=0 ]];'

Comment: You forgot a space after the `!=` , also do not use the `$` on a literal processname. `$` is only used on variables  :-)   I will edit my answer to more suit your usecase.

Comment: thanks that works! but still to the last tab it says pkill: killing pid 20822 failed : operation not permitted , any ideas? Even though thank you a lot man :D

Comment: If the operation is not permitted then pid 20822 is probably not owned by you. To test if this is the case, try to execute the same commands as root :-)

Comment: You can avoid an useless fork using something like:
while pgrep chromium &>/dev/null; do
  pkill -n -9 "chromium";
done